# Why the filter output is different when I use debug ？

Tags: javascript, json

I want to filter some data by using 'filter', but the output data is being changed, and when I try debugging to find the reason, the output data is right ...

I already tried to use 'JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))' to make it work, but it failed TAT.

```
let needGenerateDate = sDate.data.filter(item => {
  return item.week !== week;
});
console.log("needGenerateDate", needGenerateDate);
```

the `JSON.stringify(sDate.data)` is

```
"data": [
  {
      "person": [
          "person1",
          "person2",
          "person3"
      ],
      "_id": "5ca1a9bdf52c0a5710012415",
      "eventName": "special2",
      "eventNote": "没有留言呦",
      "eventType": "special",
      "week": 13,
      "time": "Sun,Mon,Wed,Tue",
      "__v": 0
  },
  {
      "person": [
          "person1",
          "person2",
          "person3",
          "person2",
          "person3"
      ],
      "_id": "5ca1ae5cd182b35534c89174",
      "eventName": "special1",
      "eventNote": "没有留言呦",
      "eventType": "special",
      "week": 13,
      "time": "Sun,Mon,Tue,Sat",
      "__v": 0
  }
]
```

When I debug the result is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsxaZ.png)

but without debugging, the result is like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdEfD.png)

I want the first one

please help a child QAQ

Comment: So is it that you want to loop over your data and extract the items within each `person` Array and then remove any duplicate "persons" ?

Comment: I want filter the data which week !== 14 ( week ) and get the data, not only get the person

Comment: I know if you get those data and try it in console directly, the result is like what I want, but I use those data in my project and run whitout debug, the result is wrong, once run with debug, the result is becoming right, this is very confuse me QAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get unique items, then flatten the array:

```js
const sDate = {
  "data": [{
      "person": [
        "person1",
        "person2",
        "person3"
      ],
      "_id": "5ca1a9bdf52c0a5710012415",
      "eventName": "special2",
      "eventNote": "没有留言呦",
      "eventType": "special",
      "week": 13,
      "time": "Sun,Mon,Wed,Tue",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "person": [
        "person1",
        "person2",
        "person3",
        "person2",
        "person3"
      ],
      "_id": "5ca1ae5cd182b35534c89174",
      "eventName": "special1",
      "eventNote": "没有留言呦",
      "eventType": "special",
      "week": 13,
      "time": "Sun,Mon,Tue,Sat",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
};

let needGenerateWeek = [...new Set(sDate.data.flatMap(({ person }) => person))];
console.log(needGenerateWeek);
```

Comment: will I use map to map the needGenerateDate and flat the person attribute and console.log it, the result is right, but will i console.log( needGenerateDate ), the result is still wrong like my second pic QAQ

Answer (score 0):

See [Set](http://%22data%22:%20[%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person%22:%20[%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person1%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person2%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person3%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20],%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_id%22:%20%225ca1a9bdf52c0a5710012415%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22eventName%22:%20%22special2%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22eventNote%22:%20%22%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%E7%95%99%E8%A8%80%E5%91%A6%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22eventType%22:%20%22special%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22week%22:%2013,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22time%22:%20%22Sun,Mon,Wed,Tue%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22__v%22:%200%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person%22:%20[%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person1%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person2%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person3%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person2%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person3%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20],%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_id%22:%20%225ca1ae5cd182b35534c89174%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22eventName%22:%20%22special1%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22eventNote%22:%20%22%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89%E7%95%99%E8%A8%80%E5%91%A6%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22eventType%22:%20%22special%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22week%22:%2013,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22time%22:%20%22Sun,Mon,Tue,Sat%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22__v%22:%200%20%20%20%7D%20]) & see [Flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) & [@babel/polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) for supporting `.flat()` in older Browsers.

```js
const data = [
  {
      "person": [
          "person1",
          "person2",
          "person3"
      ],
      "_id": "5ca1a9bdf52c0a5710012415",
      "eventName": "special2",
      "eventNote": "没有留言呦",
      "eventType": "special",
      "week": 13,
      "time": "Sun,Mon,Wed,Tue",
      "__v": 0
  },
  {
      "person": [
          "person1",
          "person2",
          "person3",
          "person2",
          "person3"
      ],
      "_id": "5ca1ae5cd182b35534c89174",
      "eventName": "special1",
      "eventNote": "没有留言呦",
      "eventType": "special",
      "week": 13,
      "time": "Sun,Mon,Tue,Sat",
      "__v": 0
  }
]

const newData = [
  ...new Set(
    data
      .map(d => d.week !== 14 ? d.person : null)
      .filter(Boolean)
      .flat()
  )
]

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: 'newData' is right, like ['person1', 'person2', 'person3']

Comment: very thanks for your answerI test it in the newest chrome, and if i only operating this data in console, the result is right, but while I put them in my project whitout debug the result is wrong, whit debug, the result is right

Comment: @陈一鹏 does my edit help? logic is  `week` !== `14` ? return `person` Array.

Comment: I find the reason from other code, but your answer let me learn some thing, this is very help for me, I am very grateful